# How to change 1 character into lower case?

Tags: html, character-encoding

I am very bloody newbie to html!

A text appears as

> DIE GUG WIRD GEGRUENDET

What I need is

> DIE gUG WIRD GEGRUENDET

Page source reads:

```
<h4>die gUG wird gegruendet</h4>
```

"h4" capitalizes the entire string but I need the "g" in front of "UG" as a lower case character for legal reasons.

How can I make this happen?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <style>

   p.lowercase {
    text-transform: lowercase;
    display: inline-block;
   }
   p.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
   }

   p.capitalize {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    display: inline-block;
   }

   </style>
   </head>
   <body>


   <h4><p class="uppercase">die</p> <p class="lowercase">g</p><p class="uppercase">UG wird gegruendet</p></h4>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```html
<h4 style="font-variant-caps: all-small-caps; font-size: 28pt">
         die <span style="font-variant-caps: initial;">g</span>UG wird gegruendet
</h4>
```

NB:: You may customize the `font-size` parameter according to your need.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. I tried it but it does not do what I need. 
It displays the entire text in upper case character but only in a smaller font.

Comment: You can change the font size according to your need. I've updated the answer, please check and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your additional proposal. However, it is not about the font size but about **lower** and **upper case** characters.